# jQuery: setInterval function stops working without reason

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've problem with setInterval() function.

I want the text to change color every few seconds (please don't ask me why).
I came up with an idea to use jQuery setInterval() function to achieve that, but it doesn't work as I would expect.

The HTML:

```
<a href="skup" id="highlight">Highlighting text</a>
```

The CSS:

```
a#highlight{
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And the JS:

```
 setInterval(function() {
    $('#highlight').css('color','#F79239');

    setTimeout(function(){$('#highlight').css('color','#000000');},2000);

}, 2000);
```

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/wbupY/

As you can se the function stops working after few changes of color.
What could be the reason for this?

Or maybe you can suggest some other solution?

Comment: `setInterval()` is JavaScript function.

Comment: @Jack: More accurately, it's a browser-supplied function. But yes, it isn't jQuery.

Comment: By scheduling a two-second timeout from within a two-second `setInterval`, you're setting up chaos. That's just a fundamentally bad idea. Instead, some form of alternation is in order (Jack has suggested one way, but you don't *need* a class for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take away settimeout and try this

```
   setInterval(function() {
             $('#highlight').css('color')  == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)' ? $('#highlight').css('color','#F79239') : $('#highlight').css('color','#000000');
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: @zorza: Only on some browsers, you can't count on the `rgb(0, 0, 0)` string being in exactly that format cross-browser. You're much better off with an explicit state variable (which, if you like, you can store on the element via `data`, or of course there's Jack's class-based solution).

Answer (score 4):

Bottom line is: don't mix `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()`.

Instead you should use only `setInterval()` and toggle the item state at each "tick" using one of the following options:

#### Using CSS class

This is arguably the most flexible, because it cleanly separates the concern of your script with the presentation of the item.

CSS:

```css
#highlight.colored {
  color: #f79239;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#highlight').toggleClass('colored');
}, 2000);
```

#### Using explicit style changes

This is less flexible, but it does allow you to toggle between more than two colors. This is the function:

```
function toggleColors(id, colors, interval)
{
    // keep these values local to the function
    var $element = $(document.getElementById(id)),
    state = 0;

    setInterval(function() {
        $element.css('color', colors[state]);
        // advance (toggle) the state for the next tick
        state = (state + 1) % colors.length;
    }, interval);
}

toggleColors('highlight', ['#f79239', 'black'], 2000);
```

Comment: +1 Similar to the answer I was about to post, but much neater!

Comment: Just for clarity: You don't *need* a class for this (though it's a good approach). But you do need to avoid the chaos of the `setTimeout` within the `setInterval` by simply alternating.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, in this particular case you could create a state variable that toggles between two colors ... just felt that CSS gives more flexibility in terms of what to change, e.g. change the background and font style as well.

Comment: I like the idea. Works perfectly, but it demands additional class, which I cannot do in this particular case. Thanks though!

Comment: @zorza Updated answer, check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have 2000 for both setInterval and setTimeout

Try this for example

```
 setInterval(function() {

      $('#highlight').css('color','#F79239');
      setTimeout(function(){$('#highlight').css('color','#000000');},2000);

}, 2100);
```

Comment: Ugh, that makes the chaos worse!!

Answer (score 0):

Both the times are the same. Reduce setTimeout to 1000